# Why is this call to a pure function with a string literal argument not optimized to a constant value?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, c11

I have a simple function which counts the letter **t** in a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int count_t_letters(const char *t) {
    int r;

    r = 0;
    while(*t) {
        if(*t == 't') {
            ++r;
        }

        ++t;
    }

    return r;
}

int main() {
    printf("%i", count_t_letters("test"));
}
```

here's the optimization I was expecting:

```
int main() {
    printf("%i", 2);
}
```

Why is this simple function not optimized like I expected in neither gcc nor clang? ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zi4Hxq))

What I figured out so far:

- Simple functions with integer pointer arguments are optimized to a constant
  ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e3lGUT))
- Using C++ with a constexpr enables this optimization ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XR8hvU))
- Clang is able to do such an optimization if there is no `++t` after the `if` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TH9aqQ))

Comment: *like expected* Is there a standard saying something about *expected*?

Comment: This is not a language-lawyer question.    It is related to quality of implementation of one compiler, not to the C language.

Comment: @tilz0R I guess not, that's simply my expectation since it would be faster and the logic to do it seems to be there? I thought there might be something that I am missing from the C standard which prevents this optimization. That's why I added the language-lawyer tag, which I agree might be confusing.

Comment: ...although `strlen` with a literal argument is likely to be reduced to a constant.

Comment: interesting... if you a normal loop over with strlen and index access then it is optimized away by both gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/9CCOBz

Comment: @bolov Wow, when did compilers got so smart?

Comment: @user2162550: from that godbolt link, for gcc sometime between 4.1.2 and 4.4.7

Comment: IMO the problem is that there's some heuristic parameter to fine tune to make it less lazy about this optimization; the fact that in C++ with `constexpr` it manages to optimize it completely is a good sign that it has all the intelligence needed for it, and it's just some parameter that, in the "normal" case, stops it from trying too hard to optimize it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm no longer so sure, the whole `constexpr` shebang seems to be implemented [completely on its own](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/constexpr.c), so it's entirely possible that the C frontend doesn't have access to the same intelligence.

Comment: you didn't specify that the function is pure, so it depends on the compiler to decide whether it's pure or not

Comment: @phuclv even marking if as such (`__attribute__((pure))`) doesn't affect the codegen, at least for gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating side effects by modifying the pointer.

If instead of incrementing `t` you simply use a normal index int and increment that instead, then gcc has no trouble optimizing it as you desire.

Modifying the pointer has side effects.

Another way, simply make a copy of the pointer, and modify the copy. Again it optimizes.

Comment: There's no conceptual difference between incrementing the pointer and incrementing an index - both are local variables, whose modifications aren't seen anywhere outside the function.

Comment: Can you give a godbolt link demonstrating that "make a copy of the point, and modify the copy" optimizes this way? I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate on those side effects? Somehow I can't figure out any way to make this optimization to happen through a copied pointer ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q8OAUY) - tested gcc and clang)

Comment: That site's javascript doesn't let me paste out from there, so that isn't useful to me. If you make a gist at github though I'd be happy to compile it in gcc to verify.

Comment: I tested in gcc before posting my answer, I have no idea about clang optimizations.
I agree with Matteo that there isn't a conceptual difference; rather, the compiler implementation is such that it doesn't do the work to tell that it is the same. Only when you isolate the changes to the function's stack frame does is it confident that the pointer doesn't get changed somewhere else.